# Send HTML email from shell CLI

Tags: linux, email, shell

I am running the cron job where there is html formatted output.
I want to send that output my email address in html format.

Is there any way to do that

```
php  /home/bla/bla_bla.php | mail -s "Bla Bla"  -s "bla@bla.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [mime-construct](http://search.cpan.org/~rosch/mime-construct-1.9/mime-construct).  It's handy for just this kind of thing.  I use it to send a generated HTML doc as part of a daily cronjob like so:

`/usr/bin/mime-construct --to "foo@bar.com" --subject "My daily html foo" --multipart multipart/alternative --type text/html --file htmlfiletosend.html`

If you don't care about the messages being multipart, you can drop that portion.  It can also take the html via stdin like so:

`php your_script.php | mime-construct --to "foo@bar.com" --subject "Foo Report" --type text/html --file -`

I don't know what distro you're using, but this is available in the main repositories for Debian and Ubuntu, I would imagine RHEL and derivatives likely have it too.

Comment: that looks good

Answer (score 1):

Add a Content-Type header such as `-a 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"'` or use a mail client that guesses the Content-Type (GNU mailutils for example probably do that).

Comment: How can i add content type in command line like above case

Comment: Depends on the `mail` implementation you're using. BSD mail: `-a`, sendmail: `(echo -e "Header: Value\n"; php bla_bla.php) | mail …`. Just look it up in the man page.